# Arrive with/at/to a person?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition do you use with *"arrive"* when you want to say that an item (e. g. parcel) arrives at a  persons doorstep?

I don't want to use "at their doorstep" but to the person themselves, so an item arriving *with/at/to* a person.

If it arrives with person A? "Arrives at a person A" sounds odd to me.

Comment: [a person's doorstep]Things and people arrive at places. But not cities. Person A brought me the parcel.

Answer (score 1):

Things arrive at a location or place, not a person. If you must use the verb 'arrive', you have to specify a place, e.g. the parcel arrived at my house. Note also that things are usually said to arrive **on** somebody's doorstep.

Answer (score 1):

We  usually say that an item *reaches* a person or *gets to* a person.

**Examples**

Has your parcel arrived?

Has your parcel reached you yet?

Has the parcel got to you yet?

Have you received the parcel?

Comment: You can also use "deliver to" in the passive voice: "Has the parcel **been delivered to** you yet?"